# Smoothing a function without changing its Riemann integral too much

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

Consider $f:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb R$ and the set $\mathcal G:=\{g\mid g\in C[a,b],g(x)\geq f(x)\}$. Show that

$$
\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\inf_{g\in\mathcal G}\int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

---

**My attempts.** First it's easy to note that $\overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leq\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx$, and $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $\Delta$ such that $\overline S(\Delta)\leq\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\epsilon$. Now we should find $g(x)$ such that $\left|\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx-\overline S(\Delta)\right|<\epsilon$ and $\color{red}{g(x)\geq f(x)}$ by **smoothing** the step function induced by $\overline S(\Delta)$.

---

**Questions.** How can we do this, noting the condition marked red? Furthermore, I know that any Riemann integrable function $f(x)$ can be approximated by a continuous function $g(x)$. What if we want $f(x)\leq g(x)$ (or $\geq$)? Can we still say this can be achieved? Finally, if we have $f(x)\in C^k[a,b]$, can we find $g(x)\in C^{k+1}[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)|\,\mathrm dx<\epsilon$?

Maybe too many questions... But I would be extremely appreciative of any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the boundary between two of the intervals of the partition. Suppose the piecewise constant function whose integral is $\overline S(\Delta)$ is equal to $p$ on one of the two intervals meeting at that boundary and to $q$ on the other, and $p<q.$ In the interval where it's equal to $p,$ find a point close to the boundary and modify the piecewise constant function so that its graph is a straight line between that point and the boundary point. Make it so close to the boundary that the integral of the resulting piecewise linear function remains less than the upper integral of $f$ plus $2\varepsilon$ after this is done at all of the boundary points.